# Distribution for this Probability density function?

Tags: probability-distributions

I having problem recognizing the following distribution. The random variable has density

$$f_\theta(x)=\frac{x}{\theta}\exp(-x^2/ 2\theta)1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$$

with respect to lebesgue, with parameter $\theta>0$.

Edit: A few more questions :D

When we talk about distribution of a random variable, there are a number of ways you can specify it right? In this case, to say that $X\sim R(\theta)$ is equivalent to saying $X$ has probability measure $\nu=f_{\theta}\cdot m$ ?

furthermore, how can I find the distribution of $X^2$?

Comment: The Rayleigh distribution is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Rayleigh distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) with parameter $θ$ instead of $σ^2$ (as given in Wikipedia):

> The probability density function of the Rayleigh distribution is
>
> $$f(x;\sigma) = \frac{x}{\sigma^2} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}, \quad x \geq 0$$
>
> where $\sigma$ is the scale parameter of the distribution. The cumulative distribution function is
> $$F(x) = 1 - e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}$$
> for $x \in [0,\infty).$

Comment: Have a follow up question in my edit if you don't mind.

Comment: @ChuckP The probability that $X^2 > y$ is the probability that $X> \sqrt{y}$, since all is positive.

Comment: I see now, it gives me exp dist with 1/2\theta as rate parameter.